# Group query result rows by one column and present rows as HTML unordered lists in respective divs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

My query outputs this in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT service_names.id, service_names.name as service, 
service_titles.name as title, service_titles.id as service_title_id FROM `service_names` INNER 
JOIN service_titles ON title_id = service_titles.id WHERE service_titles.user_id = ? AND 
service_titles.slide_id = ?")) {

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $slide_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($service_id, $service_name, $service_title, $service_title_id);
$stmt->store_result();

$result_array = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($result_array[$service_title])){
        $result_array[$service_title] = array();
    }
    $result_array[$service_title][] = array('service_name'=>$service_name,'service_id'=>$service_id);
}

$html = "";
foreach($result_array as $key => $value){
    $html .= "
    <div class=\"list\">
        <h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id={ GOES HERE }>$key</span></h3>
            <ul>";
        foreach($result_array[$key] as $service){
            $html .= "<li><span id=\"".$service['service_id']."\">".$service['service_name']."</span></li>\n"; 
        }
    $html .= "</ul></div>";
}

echo $html;
$stmt->close();
}

?>
```

**What this code is producing is:**

[image]

What I need is to grab the `service_title_id` and place it in the code:

```
<h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id={ GOES HERE }>$key</span></h3>
```

I am using a jQuery inline edit script, and it needs a unique ID assigned to it.  I have the value in a variable **$service_title_id** it's just a matter of integrating it into the array, which I am getting a little confused with all the different arrays and values.

Comment: You can't use `service_title_id` as an id because it is not unique. What are you actually trying to do? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: it will be fine because in my inline editor, if I edit it, so I change "Maintenance" to "New Value" it will update in the database for that id (1) to "new Value" and it will update all of them (as it should)

Comment: You still can't use this as an HTML id - if you do it won't do anything useful. HTML id's must be unique. If you need the data on the page, you will have to put it in another element, like a `<span>` or an `<input>`, depending on what you are actually need to do with the data at the client side.

Comment: I think in his code it IS unique. It was a little bit hard to follow, but you'll notice "Maintenance" (id of 1) is only getting printed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way, that requires minimum changes in your script, is to add `service_title_id` to every service and get it from first element of an array:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($result_array[$service_title])){
        $result_array[$service_title] = array();
    }
    $result_array[$service_title][] = array(
        'service_name'=>$service_name,
        'service_id'=>$service_id,
        'service_title_id'=>$service_title_id
    );
}

<h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id={$result_array[$key][0]['service_title_id']}>$key</span></h3>
```

other and cleaner way will be to change structure of array holding all services to look like this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($result_array[$service_title])){
        $result_array[$service_title_id] = array(
            'service_title' => $service_title
            'services' => array(),
        );
    }
    $result_array[$service_title_id]['services'][] = array(
        'service_name'=>$service_name,
        'service_id'=>$service_id
    );
}


$html = "";
foreach($result_array as $service_title_id => $service_details){
    $html .= "
    <div class=\"list\">
        <h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id=\"{$service_title_id}\">{$service_details['title']}</span></h3>
            <ul>";
        foreach($service_details['services'] as $service){
            $html .= "<li><span id=\"{$service['service_id']}\">{$service['service_name']}</span></li>\n"; 
        }
    $html .= "</ul></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the commenters about having unique html id's are on to something, but here's some improved PHP for you.  I renamed your variables to make things clearer

```
$html = "";
foreach($result_array as $service_title => $services){
    $html .= "
    <div class=\"list\">
        <h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id={$services[0]['service_id']}>$service_title</span></h3>
            <ul>";
        foreach($services as $service){
            $html .= "<li><span id=\"".$service['service_id']."\">".$service['service_name']."</span></li>\n"; 
        }
    $html .= "</ul></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty but will get the job done:

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT service_names.id, service_names.name as service, 
service_titles.name as title, service_titles.id as service_title_id FROM `service_names` INNER 
JOIN service_titles ON title_id = service_titles.id WHERE service_titles.user_id = ? AND 
service_titles.slide_id = ?")) {

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $user_id, $slide_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($service_id, $service_name, $service_title, $service_title_id);
$stmt->store_result();

$result_array = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!isset($result_array[$service_title])){
        $result_array[$service_title] = array();
    }
    $result_array[$service_title . ':' . $service_id][] = $service_name;
}

$html = "";
foreach($result_array as $key => $value){
        list ($title, $id) = explode(':', $key);
    $html .= "
    <div class=\"list\">
        <h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id=\"$id\">$title</span></h3>
            <ul>";
        foreach($value as $service){
            $html .= "<li><span>$service</span></li>\n"; 
        }
    $html .= "</ul></div>";
}

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop to this:

```
foreach($result_array as $key => $value){
    $html .= "
    <div class=\"list\">
        <h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id=\"service_title_id_{$value[0]['service_title_id']}\">$key</span></h3>
            <ul>";
        foreach($value as $service){
            $html .= "<li><span id=\"".$service['service_id']."\">".$service['service_name']."</span></li>\n"; 
        }
    $html .= "</ul></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to:

```
 $result_array[$service_title][] = array('service_name'=>$service_name,'service_id'=>$service_id, 'service_title_id' => $service_title_id);
```

And this line to:

```
<h3 class=\"secondary\"><span id=\"".$."\">$result_array[$key]['service_title_id']</span></h3>
```

It's a little bit redundant, but basically you are putting the service_title_id in the second dimension of the array and using it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Build your grouped array from your query results by pushing whole rows into a new array using the `title` (or `title_id`) as the first level key.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT service_titles.id   AS title_id,
       service_titles.name AS title,
       service_names.id    AS service_id,
       service_names.name  AS service,
FROM service_names
JOIN service_titles ON title_id = service_titles.id
WHERE service_titles.user_id = ?
      AND service_titles.slide_id = ?
SQL;
$resultSet = $mysqli->execute_query($sql, [$user_id, $slide_id]);
$grouped = [];
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
    $grouped[$row['title']][] = $row;
}
```

Then traverse the populated array.  An empty group will not exist, so you can safely access `[0]` in the first row of a group to access the `title_id` value.

```
foreach ($grouped as $title => $rows) {
    ?>
    <div class="list">
        <h3 class="secondary">
            <span id="<?php echo $rows[0]['title_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $title; ?>
            </span>
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                printf(
                    '<li><span id="%d">%s</span></li>' . "\n\t\t\t",
                    $row['service_id'],
                    $row['service']
                ); 
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```